# Sinônimo pra Cânone

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, sinônimos

Estou procurando um sinônimo de fácil compreensão por quem lê para a palavra [cânone](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2none_(m%C3%BAsica))

A grosso modo, um cânone é como uma segunda voz cantando a mesma coisa que a voz principal porém com uma entonação menos intensa e com um tempo ligeiramente atrasado.

Eu até tentei pesquisar sinônimos, tanto em português quanto em inglês, no Thesaurus, mas não achei nada que, além de soar simples, não fosse... "lexicamente feio"

O sinônimo mais elegante, contextualmente falando, que eu encontrei, foi **compasso**, mas eu não encontrei essa palavra em nenhum lugar estando ela relacionada com **cânone**.

E como não entendo de música...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Estou procurando um sinônimo de fácil compreensão por quem lê para a
> palavra cânone

Que eu saiba, não existe. Cânone é cânone, e é uma coisa bem específica.

> A grosso modo, um cânone é como uma segunda voz cantando a mesma coisa
> que a voz principal porém com uma entonação menos intensa e com um
> tempo ligeiramente atrasado.

Cânone é um determinado tipo de composição musical (ou de arranjo coral). Num cânone, duas (ou mais) vozes cantam a mesma melodia com a mesma letra, mas defasada no tempo. Isso significa que uma parte da melodia é capaz de servir de baixo para a outra. Funciona mais ou menos assim

> 1ª voz: `Como pode o peixe vivo viver fora dágua fria / Como poderei viver sem a tua...`
>
> 2ª voz: ..........................................`Como pode o peixe vivo viver fora dágua fria / Como...`

Num cânone, "a segunda voz canta a mesma coisa que a voz principal", porém com "com um tempo ligeiramente (ou não tão ligeiramente) atrasado". Mas o cânone não é essa segunda voz, é a composição como um todo.

> O sinônimo mais elegante, contextualmente falando, que eu encontrei,
> foi compasso, mas eu não encontrei essa palavra em nenhum lugar
> estando ela relacionada com cânone.

"Compasso" não é, de forma alguma, sinônimo de "cânone". Toda e qualquer música tem compassos (pelo menos na tradição musical ocidental desde a renascença; o cantochão não tem compassos), que são divisões no tempo marcando a acentuação (FORTE, fraco, fraco, FORTE, fraco fraco, etc.) Um cânone tem compassos, mas também uma fuga, uma sonata, um rondó, uma sinfonia, uma valsa, um samba. O que ocorre no cânone é que a segunda voz, que entra em retardo, tem o seu primeiro compasso coincidindo com o segundo, ou terceiro, ou vigésimo sétimo, etc., compasso da primeira voz, de maneira que o tempo acentuado de cada uma coincide com o tempo acentuado da outra.

No linque que você postou ([Frére Jacques](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2none_(m%C3%BAsica)#/media/File:YB4001Canon_Frere_Jacques.png)), observe a partitura: você verá que a pauta de cada uma das vozes é dividida por pequenas linhas verticais - e que essas linhas coincidem para todas as vozes. O que está contido entre duas dessas linhas é um compasso. O cânone é a peça musical ("a música") como um todo.

---

Qual o contexto em que você precisa do sinônimo? E em qual contexto aparece a palavra "cânone", que você quer substituir? É indispensável que a forma musical seja essa?

Comment: Pois é... Nesse meio tempo eu acabei deixando a "frescura" de lado e mantive como cânone mesmo. Se perguntarem, eu explico. O contexto, por incrível que pareça, é o nome, confesso que não sei bem se de um objeto ou de um efeito, formado, sempre, por uma terminologia musical (cânone, canção, melodia...) seguida de um substantivo qualquer cabível no contexto. Quanto ao "sinônimo" compasso, acabou então que foi um falso-positivo, fazer o quê...

Comment: Esse último parágrafo da resposta é importante, porque em outros contextos – que não o musical – cânone tem outros significados. @BrunoAugusto

Answer (score 5):

Se você não entende de música, se a maioria das pessoas também não entende, se nenhum dos dois faz a menor ideia do que é cânone, então você tem que compreender que não há "*sinônimo de fácil compreensão*" para cânone porque o próprio significado "cânone" não é facilmente compreendido.

Mas você deu um significado quando fez a pergunta e com ele já respondeu sua própria pergunta: "*cânone é como uma segunda voz cantando a mesma coisa que a voz principal porém com uma entonação menos intensa e com um tempo ligeiramente atrasado*".

O sinônimo de fácil compreensão para Cânone é [segunda voz](http://www.mundobends.com.br/tecnica-segunda-voz-como-fazer/) porque segunda voz é só aquilo que se compreende facilmente de uma maneira geral.

Se você precisar de mais do que "*segunda voz*", tem que complementar o conceito da forma como você fez... A não ser que alguém conheça música, não há outra maneira neste caso.

Comment: *Segunda voz defasada, atrasada*?

Comment: Eu estava procurando por uma palavra única ou que fosse uma expressão composta, hifenizada ou não, que fosse ligeiramente mais simples que cânone.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Mas aí eu concordo com o Eduardo. O problema não está na palavra *cânone* ser desconhecida; está é em o conceito em si ser desconhecido. Portanto, mesmo que haja um sinónimo (não sei se há), provavelmente também não seria compreendido.

Comment: Também concordo, mas quem não arrisca, não petisca. Vai que existe e alguém conheça ;)

Comment: Cânone é nome que se dá ao material original produzido pelo artista original, então se não explicar o significado como termo da música, um não músico provavelmente não entenderá .